# Non separable solution of a PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, symmetry

Can anyone give me a non separable (and non trivial) solution (in closed form) to the PDE:
$$
yu_{xx}+u_{yy}+y^2u=0.
$$
Is there a nice way to use symmetries to find such a solution?

Comment: hint : reduce to the canonical form for $y < 0$ and $y > 0$

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: see this link : http://faculty.uml.edu/spennell/Teaching/PDE/classification.pdf

Comment: So summing up an infinite amount of separable solutions won't do the trick? (i.e. the generalized Fourier series approach). What kind of boundary conditions do you have?